# are there any samples on how to use chat api with facebook c# sdk

Tags: chat, facebook-c#-sdk

Can I use the Facebook Chat API with the Facebook C# SDK? If so, are there any samples for using the Chat API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK doesn't support the Facebook chat API.

Facebook chat is based on the XMPP protocol, so you might want to search for XMPP libraries written in C# instead.

You can find a list of XMPP libraries at http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/